# vue 3 ElementPlusError: [ElPagination] Deprecated usages detected

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, element-plus

I'm having problem with Vue 3 element-plus el-pagination, i have this warning:

```
ElementPlusError: [ElPagination] Deprecated usages detected, please refer to the el-pagination documentation for more details
    ElementPlusError error.ts:4
    debugWarn error.ts:13
    setup pagination.ts:211
    renderComponentRoot runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:876
    componentUpdateFn runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5995
    run reactivity.esm-bundler.js:176
    update runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6126
    setupRenderEffect runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6136
    mountComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5904
error.ts:14:12
```

My code works but can't find the reason of this showing. Tried what element-plus have on their website but without success, when i remove page size related options, warning dissapears.

```
<el-pagination 
@size-change="changePerPage" 
@current-change="changeCurrentPage" 
:current-page="currentPage" 
:page-size="per_page"                
:page-sizes="[5, 10, 20]" 
layout="total, sizes, prev, pager, next" 
:total="usersData.total" 
class="mt-2 border p-2" 
/>

const currentPage = ref(1);
const per_page = ref(5)

function changeCurrentPage(val: any) {
    currentPage.value = val
    search()
};

function changePerPage(val: any) {
    per_page.value = val
    search()
};

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    search()
})
```